# Eigenvalue of a Casimir Element

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

For a simple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ which contains a subalgebra isomorphic to $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R})$, let $\pi:\mathfrak{g}\to\mathrm{End}(V)$ be a non-trivial irreducible representation. Define the trace bilinear form $B_V$ on $\mathfrak{g}$ by $B(X,Y)=\mathrm{tr}(\pi(X)\pi(Y))$. Then there exists a Casimir element $\Delta$ in the center of $U(\mathfrak{g})$ (by universal property). Now I'm trying to show that the eigenvalue of $\Delta$ on $V$ is $\frac{1}{\dim(V)}$.

I've proved that $\pi$ is faithful and $B_V$ is nondegenerate. Taking the trace, I concluded that
$$\mathrm{tr}(\Delta)=\sum\limits_{i}\mathrm{tr}(\pi(x_i)\pi(y_i))=\sum\limits_iB(x_i,y_i)=\dim\mathfrak{g}$$
after fixing a basis $(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ of $\mathfrak{g}$ and its determined dual basis $(y_1,\cdots,y_n)$. What to do next to compute and verify the eigenvalue of $\Delta$ on $V$?

Comment: Because $\Delta$ is in the center of the universal enveloping algebra, by Schur's lemma it acts as a scalar  $\lambda_V$ on an irreducible representation $V$. It follows that the trace of $\pi(\Delta)$ equals $\lambda_V\cdot \dim V$. It looks like there is some kind of a normalization conflict (if not an error)?! May be the Casimir element is firs normalized w.r.t. the adjoint representation. I need more coffee, and the time to locate my copy of Humphreys :-)

Comment: Yeah as @JyrkiLahtonen points out, the correct eigenvalue here should probably be $\frac{\dim \mathfrak{g}}{\dim V}$ (obviously this is all up to an overall scale anyway but this is the one obtained directly from the trace form of the representation) - see Humphreys, section 6.2.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. This question is from an exercise of chapter 12 in Lie Groups by Bump. I’ll chech the book you suggested me to read:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be something incorrect in the original question. Review a proposition in Bump's *Lie Groups*.

> **Proposition 10.2.** *Let $\pi:\mathfrak{g}\to\mathrm{End}(V)$ be an irreducible representation of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. If $c$
> is in the center of $U(\mathfrak{g})$, then there exists a scalar
> $\lambda$ such that $\pi(c)=\lambda I_V$.*

Back to this question, it immediately follows from the above proposition that $\pi(\Delta)=\lambda I_V$ for a certain scalar $\lambda$, which can be regarded as the eigenvalue of $\Delta$. Taking traces on both sides, we obtain $$\mathrm{tr}(\Delta)=\dim\mathfrak{g}=\lambda\dim V,$$
i.e., the eigenvalue $\lambda=\frac{\dim\mathfrak{g}}{\dim V}$.

Comment: I think the issue here is in what you are defining $\Delta$ as. Any rescaling of it will give you another Casimir element so you have to decide what the scale is. In Humphreys, for example he uses the trace form directly (as you seemed to) to get one with eigenvalues $\frac{\dim \mathfrak{g}}{\dim V}$ (note this implicitly depends on the choice of $V$). But you could just choose any one in its span instead. Often the one for $V = \mathfrak{g}$ is the one called "the" Casimir element (this is not even to mention the non-quadratic Casimir elements)